# Bidirectional Publisher/Subscriber TCP connection handhsake protocol

Tags: sockets, distributed-computing, publish-subscribe

I want to write a publisher/subscriber distributed application where each node can publish and subscribe data (by topic) at the same time. For simplicity assume there is a phase where the publishers / subscribers first report what they want to publish / subscribe to a central server. When this completes the server sends information to the subscribers where they should connect to for receiving a publication (by topic). Because a node can publish and subscribe, a node A can connect to another node B to subscribe and then node B can also connect to node A because it wants to subscribe to some data that node A publishes. It is a cyclic "dependency".

The problem I have now is that I do want to keep only one socket for the communication of these two nodes on both sides, both, for publication of data and receiving of data, because a socket is already a bidirectional construct. Assume both nodes have a socket listener which listens to a port. Both nodes connect at the same time to each other, which connection will be accepted and which is being discarded? What protocol does fit good for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A socket may be bidirectional but it can't be connected to two endpoints at the same time. You need:

- an active (client) connection to the central server
- another one to connect to whatever the central server tells you to connect to
- a listening (server) socket so you can accept inbound connections
- an accepted socket per inbound connection.

Answer (score 0):

This process is similar to the handshake procedure used by this [open source networking library](http://www.networkcomms.net). Once a connection has been established either A -> B or B -> A, the single existing connection is then used for all communication. Your best bet is possibly to see it in action by checking out either the [Getting Started](http://www.networkcomms.net/getting-started/) section or the [how to create a client server application](http://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/) article.

Answer (score 0):

A good match for your problem could be some [DDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_distribution_service) (Data Distribution Service) implementation. It completely removes any notions of concrete endpoints and only focus on topic/data. Any node can act both as topic/data producers and consumers. The DDS middle ware takes care of all addressing, state propagation, serializing/de-serializing, flow control etc. It also handles (auto)discovery of new topics and data.

Here's a [short video describing how DDS works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-saogMmKOo):

Here's a [list of various DDS implementations](http://portals.omg.org/dds/category/web-links/vendors) (both commercial and free).